# Order in if-clause

Tags: java, if-statement

What's the difference between

```
if( true == getBooleanValue() )
```

and

```
if( getBooleanValue() == true )
```

where getBooleanValue() returns true or false ?

Comment: both are equivalent, and both are unneccesary, you would just write `if (getBooleanValue())`

Comment: Also see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions but note that the subtle differences between java and c++ in regards of such kind of expressions.

Comment: Which do you feel is simpler/clearer?

Comment: And side note: actually, methods returning a boolean ... should be better called like `isFoo()`, or 'areBarsFubberBlub()'. In other words: you make your code read like **if** *something is* then ...

Answer (score 2):

There is no functional difference, but you should use:

```
if (getBooleanValue())
```

Answer (score 1):

**a)**
`if(true==getBooleanValue())` is the same as `if(getBooleanValue())`
**b)** `if(getBooleanValue() == true)` will first evaluate `getBooleanValue()` and then check if it is equal to `true`
In this case that may not make a difference, but in more complex conditions it may. For example `if(a==b && getBooleanValue())` Here the `getBooleanValue()` would not get executed when `a==b` is `false`.